# Three Visual Puzzles

Tags: mathematics, visual, mazes, alphametic

I'm designing a puzzle game, and am trying to play-test some concepts. Can you solve these?

**108153767833 = A + B + C.
What are the components and why?**

[image: A = ?]

[image: B = ?]

[image: C = ?]

Note for C: As a hint to correct an oversight, the product of the digits in C is 2488320.

Comment: Yep. They are related.

Comment: yeah never mind, I should have looked closer:-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Partial:

C

> Mazes with the following rules:
>  1. Take the shortest path possible starting at green and ending at red.
>  2. If yellow dots, all must be "retrieved" before reaching red.
>  3. Red cannot be crossed, thus only reached once.
>  4. Colored squares are "locked doors" that are only passable once you have "retrieved" the associated colored triangle.
>  Based on these rules and clarification provided by a hint and a comment, we can now solve the last maze, which gives us a solution of
>  $99453888111$

---

A

> Found by @deep_thought. Please review their answer.

---

B

> After working through this and making a mess of a wall of text, I found that @JonMark_Perry was better able to succinctly describe the process.
>  Let's look at #1 for an example though:
>  Example 1. a_1_z -> pp=11
>  p falls in the range of a to z, thus p is 1. As p is printed twice, the result is 11.
>
>  Example 2. a_1_ij_2_op_3_z -> pi = 31 ty =33
>  set p-z includes p, t, and y, thus p, t, and y are all 3.
>  set a-i includes i, thus i is 1
>
>  Example 3 gets a little interesting. 
>  Here, q_1_k translates to ^k-q = 1, or letters not in the set of k-q get +1.
>  3 also introduces the idea that set values can stack.
>  As such, p is in set a-p and not in set k-q, thus is 1 + 1 or 2.
>  l is in set a-p, k-q, l-z, thus is 1 + -1 or 2. (Doesn't get the 1 from ^k-q as l is not *not* in k-q.
>
>  Thus brings us to Example 5, which we must solve to find B.
>  The rule sets are as follows:
>  a-z = 1
>  a-m = 1 n-z = 2
>  a-p = 2 q-z = 1
>  a-e = 1 f-z = 3
>  a-j = 1 k-s = 2 t-z = 3
>  a-p = -2 q-z = -1
>  These thus result in the following letter values:
>  p = 1 2 2 3 2 -2 = 8
>  i = 3 1 = 4
>  t = 1 2 3 3 = 9
>  y = 1 2 3 3 = 9
>  l = 1 1 3 2 = 7
>  e = 1 1 1 1 = 4
>  a = 1 1 1 1 = 4
>  s = 1 2 3 2 = 8
>  And when the word *pityplease* is decoded, we get
>  B = $8499874484$
>  However, this value appears to be incorrect.
>
>  **Actually, what if a_-2_pq_-1_z were instead just a_-1_z**:
>  p = 1 2 2 3 2 -1 = 9
>  i = 1 1 2 3 1 -1 = 7
>  t = 1 2 1 3 3 -1 = 9
>  y = 1 2 1 3 3 -1 = 9
>  l = 1 1 2 3 2 -1 = 8
>  e = 1 1 2 1 1 -1 = 5
>  a = 1 1 2 1 1 -1 = 5
>  s = 1 2 1 3 2 -1 = 8
>  $9799985585$
>  Perfect! Just what we needed!

Answer:

> If T is $109253878934$
>  And A is confirmed $5238$
>  And C is confirmed $99453888111$
>  Then B must be $109253878934$ - $5238$ - $99453888111$ = $9799985585$
>  However, I can't get my B formula to match.
>  Actually, if we use the slightly modified rule for B5, then we get the desired result!
>  Technically not correct, but I'm happy with it for now.

Comment: Looks like you are correct. Totally an oversight on my part. Nice job finding that. My intended solution was none of those three, interestingly enough.

Comment: you can have 94492888111 as well.

Comment: For clarity, my previous comment was in reference to your solution for C.

Comment: Getting somewhere, but not quite. Check out my added note if you'd like to find the exact answer for C.

Comment: Yes but my current C value actually works for that hint @NigelMNZ.

Comment: Crap, got me again. Your C and A are correct. My total for A+B+C was off. I've adjusted it accordingly.

Comment: Your logic for B is completely correct, so I'm marking this as solved. As written in puzzle, the solution is actually 8699874484. Your first attempt at B just about got this, but you just miscalculated "i", which is actually 6 (1 1 2 3 1 -2). Unfortunately for me, I misrepresented the sum again. I've fixed the sum for future solvers. Thanks much for the great effort despite the bugs!

Answer (score 5):

**Partial answer**

For A,

> if we ignore tilt and position, then I can fit the four numbers at the top with: colour is power of ten, shape is digit (star is one), filled is positive, empty is negative; sum all shapes.
>  - filled red star = 1
>  - filled red triangle and filled red square = 3 + 4 = 7
>  - filled blue pentagon and empty red heptagon = 50 - 7 = 43
>  - filled green triangle and empty blue square and empty red enneagon = 300 - 40 - 9 = 251
>  This gives P^1 = 157, P^2 = 857, P^3 = 1201. These are prime factors of the number at the bottom. P^4 is the missing factor is 3023. Their sum is A = 5238.

Part B: no clue

Part C: already solved by @Dorrulf

Comment: Nicely done for A!

Comment: Indeed, very nice.

Answer (score 5):

B.

> Every a_b_c triple forms a range in the alphabet that scores b points, for example a_1_m means that every letter in [a,m] scores 1 point, with wrapround if the range is backwards. I get $B=8699874484$.